# How can i fix/restore linux permissions without reinstalling / deleting my files?

Tags: linux, file, permissions

I was trying to change permissons of a folder, and i typed in:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /.
```

I believe it changed my **whole** system's permissons.
I can no longer connect using ssh/stfp to it.

How can i **restore** my system permissions **without** reinstalling / deleting **any** of my files?

1. I am using Ubuntu Server
2. The computer is 64 bit
3. The files / servers are working fine (HTTP, Games, ETC)

Comment: Install windows 10. And the answer: nohow

Comment: try fixing the premissions on `$HOME/.ssh` and all the files there (can you do that?) `ssh` will (in some installations) refuse to start if the perms on the key file (and maybe others) are not minimal (i.e.600/700). BUT not really a programming Q suitable for Stackoverflow, Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and maybe take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com) before posting more Qs here.
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

As per this link https://askubuntu.com/questions/508359/restore-default-system-file-folder-permessions you can restore the default system file/folder permissions in linux

and check with the Ubuntu version too.